# How to change the value of an asp label with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to add an error label to the top of a panel I have. I have a button created in C# on page load that calls a JavaScript function that I want to display an error message on my panel when clicked.

C#:

```
private void CreateButton(int pID, string changeType)
{
    ASPxButton btn = new ASPxButton();
    btn.Text = "Execute Request";
    btn.ID = "btn" + changeType;
    btn.AutoPostBack = false;
    btn.ClientSideEvents.Click = GetClientSideEventHandler(string.Format("OnProcessRequest(s, e, '{0}','{1}')", pID.ToString(), changeType));
    TableRow oRow = new TableRow();
    TableCell oCell = new TableCell();
    oCell.CssClass = "table-cell";
    oCell.Controls.Add(btn);
    oRow.Cells.Add(oCell);
    tblButtons.Rows.Add(oRow);

}
```

JS:

```
function OnProcessRequest$(pID, pChangeType) {
    document.getElementById('errLabel').value = "Test";
}
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:Label ID="errLabel" runat="server"/>
```

When this code runs, it always throws the following error:

Error: Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference.

I have tried also using:

document.getElementById('<%=errLabel.ClientID%>').value = "Test";

but this also throws the error.

How can I change the value of this label when this button is clicked in JS?

Comment: I'm assuming the $ in  `OnProcessRequest$` is a typo in the question only as your C# version has no $ . Next check the rendered HTML for the value of  ID on the label also check what is rendered by `'<%=errLabel.ClientID%>'`, do they match?

Comment: @JonP The $ was added by another dev. I'm not sure what exactly it's for, but if I remove it the function is never called. How do I check the rendered HTML? I'm using VS 2019 Community.

Comment: To check the rendered HTML, view page source in the browser of the served page. It also looks like there could be another js `OnProcessRequest` somewhere in your code as the one referenced in the C# has 4 parameters not 2

Comment: Ok this doesn't explain the undefined error  but `label` doesn't have a value `property` (in the DOM anyway) you want `document.getElementById('errLabel').innerHTML= "Test";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to change a asp.net label in JavaScript, you can do this:

(we assume you set the label client id mode>

So, if we have  label on the page, you can do this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
```

JavaScript to change above is this:

```
 var lbl = document.getElementById('<%=Label1.ClientID%>');

 lbl.innerText = "Js lable text changed";
```

Or

```
 lbl.innerHTML = "<h2>this is some big text by js</h2>"
```

Be VERY careful with case, and VERY careful with extra spaces etc. in the get Element.

Also, do NOT forget to include the Text="" in your label!!!! (you are missing this!!!).

JavaScript is VERY flakey - one small wrong move, and it just rolls over and goes home. (and the debugger in browsers is on par with a trip to the dentist).

You can also use jQuery.

The above thus becomes this:

```
var lbl = $('#Label1');
lbl1.text("js jquery text change");
```

Now, lets do the same for a text box.

our asp.net text box:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:TextBox>
```

JavaScript:

```
var txt = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>');
txt.value = "This is js text for text box";
```

And as jQuery:

```
var txt = $('#TextBox1');
txt.val("js jquery text for the text box");
```

So, for a asp.net label? You use innerText, or innerHTML.
(or text("your text here") with jQuery)

and with jQuery, you use .value without ()

Comment: Thanks!  Using the innerText/innerHTML method you suggested still resulted in the same errors, but the JQuery you provided worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding ClientIDMode="Static" to your label if that property is available to you. Or you could add ClientID="errLabel" as an alternative. What's happening is asp.net will automatically give your field a generated id for closure on the client side so it will not match your id "errLabel".

```
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="errLabel" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
```

OR

```
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="errLabel" ClientID="errLabel"></asp:Label>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_Control_ClientIDMode

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions, however the error remains.